# C# : About the Themes & wallpaper in windows, how to keep the slideshow.ini don't change?

Tags: c#, windows, themes, wallpaper

For some reason,  I am working for resetting the wallpaper by using the **SystemParametersInfo** in C#.
But every time i have done this work, the  slideshow.ini in the C:\Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes will be reset to emptytoo. 
I need it to be the same file before I set the new wallpaper to desktop.

Is there any API or any way can done this job?

And is there any API can get the Message about the User Change Themes->Single wallpaper(new themes)?

I have tried WM_THEMESCHANGE & WM_PAINT, non of them can reach my needs.

Just change the wallpaper but not reset the slidershow.ini, which act just like the "Theme", change the photo after a period of time and keep the slideshow.ini.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer into your project and integrate it in your default wallpaper change code and use it for the regular wallpaper change. By setting the readonly property to true of the ini file you can protect it from any changes.

```
        using System.IO;

        string iniPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini";
        File.SetAttributes(iniPath, File.GetAttributes(iniPath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```